# Is there a way to print out the entire sorted lists in addition to displaying the average, highest and lowest temperature?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to print out an entire sorted list of temperatures, in addition to displaying the average, highest and lowest temperature?

Comment: it only displays average, highest and lowest temperature. I want to display the inputted  temperatures be displayed.  how can i do that? any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Comment: it only displays average, highest and lowest temperature. I need to display  the inputted  array of temperatures.  how can i do that? any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I can't paste the code here. It says "too long".  I'm so sorry I'm new and just registered. Can you please tell me if there's a way for me so that i can show you the code?

Comment: Paste it on https://pastebin.com and share the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=QPcfqny7

Comment: I just pasted the link. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Golda: We don't need complete large programs. You should create a copy of your program, and remove all the unrelated parts from your code. This should give you a minimal problem which you **can** post here. (And one reason we ask this, is because most problems are easily solvable once you have them isolated)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the entire **sorted** list, just print from the `temperatures[]` array.

For sorting though, include `<algorithm>` and use the `sort()` function.

Append this code in your `main()`:

```
//Sorting the array in increasing order.
sort(temperatures,temperatures+days);
//Printing the sorted temperatures.
for (int i = 0; i < days; ++i)
     cout<<temperatures[i]<<" ";
```